# PHP same value different result

Tags: php, oop, return

I am running in to a strange issue and i don't really know what is causing it i have a class to update a users activity a log kind of thing. it looks like this :

```
class activiteit
{
    private $dbc;
    public $uid;

    public function __construct(){
        require 'dbc.php';
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
        $this->uid = $this->getUserId();
        var_dump($this->uid);
    }

    //bunch of functions here....

    public function getUserId(){
        $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $_SESSION['usr']);
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_users WHERE gebruikersnaam='$usr'";

        $res = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $sql); 
        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        return $res['id'];
    }
}
```

the value of var dump is this string(1) "7"
and the rest of the code does not work.
but if i change the code to this

```
class activiteit
{
    private $dbc;
    public $uid;

    public function __construct(){
        require 'dbc.php';
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
        $this->uid = $this->getUserId();
        var_dump($this->uid);
    }

    //bunch of functions here....

    public function getUserId(){
        $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $_SESSION['usr']);
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_users WHERE gebruikersnaam='$usr'";

        $res = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $sql); 
        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        return "7";
    }
}
```

the value of var dump is still string(1) "7"
and the rest of the code now works fine.

Comment: Why the down vote, am i missing something?

Comment: try to add ";" return $res['id'] to return $res['id']; p.s. not mine downvote

Comment: @droid It is there in the code removed it by accident in the post ;)

Comment: try return 7; instead of return "7"; ?

Comment: Return "7" and return 7 both work but when getting it from data base it magically stops to work also tried intval on the return didn't make a difference

Comment: what if you add echo cnt+1 to each function after var_dump($this->uid); and see at what function execution stops? any errors in log?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Droid but i fixed it i have no idea why it works now but im not gonna touch it anymore to be safe ;) i was adding a bunch of white lines above and under the function getUserId to make it more readable and it magically worked! if some one knows why adding white lines changes things please let me know i am very curious now